# Could not cast value of type

Tags: web-services, swift

when i call web service then i got error "Could not cast value of type".

```
 var params: [String: String] =
            ["udid": layout.udId, "email": emailtxt.text, "password": passtxt.text]

            api.sendPostCall(params, url: "http://doxnation.com/api"){( success:Bool,reult: AnyObject) -> () in

                if(success) {
                }
                else{
                    println("Error HERE");
                }
            }
```

and here is my sendPostCall function

```
func sendPostCall(params : AnyObject, url : String, postCompleted : (succeeded: Bool, result: AnyObject) -> ()) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


    var err: NSError?
    let data = (params as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) // Error here
}
```

i don't understand how can i solve this?
i also tried

```
 let data = (params as! NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: In which line you getting this error?

Comment: let data = (params as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) // Error here

Comment: Your params is dictionary. But you are forcibly converting it to NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just replace

```
let data = (params as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

with

```
let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options:NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error: &err)
```

if any one has better solution then kindly share please with me

Thanks to all